# Window slows down on mouse move

Tags: c++, sfml

I have an SFML RenderWindow which runs at a framerate of 30, but when I move my mouse over the window it noticeably slows down till an unacceptable framerate (at 3 FPS or slower). When I stop moving the mouse, the framerate returns to normal speed. The weird thing is that my code doesn't listen for a mouse event. Does anyone have a clue how to fix this?

My Code:

```
int Window::run()
{
    while(window->isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while(window->pollEvent(event))
            onEvent(event);

        loop();

        window->clear(bgcolor);
        for(int i=0; i<panels.size(); i++)
            panels[i]->draw(window);
        window->display();
    }

    return 0;
}

void Window::onEvent(sf::Event event)
{
    if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
        window->close();
    else if(event.type == sf::Event::Resized)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<panels.size(); i++)
            panels[i]->repaint();
    }

}
```

Comment: *an unacceptable framerate (somewhere between 300 or slower).* 300 FPS?

Comment: Oh I made a typo. I meant 3 FPS, not 300